# Moodle Restrict submission Notification to assigned teacher

Tags: notifications, moodle

The Notify graders setting to 'Yes' in Assignment settings is sending notifications to all the teachers, whether they are the allocated markers for a particular student assignment or not. There doesn't seem to be a way to prevent notifications to all the teachers rather than only send it to the one allocated teacher. Looking for a fix?

Answer (score 0):

It is not a bug, since the setting says "Notify grader**S**", not one particular grader. So there is no fix, because your request assumes new functionality